# How can I create array of classname for comparision in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, class

I am using Delphi. I have a root class and many derived class from the root, the name of the class says TROOT, TA, TB, TC ... In the code, I have some code to control the flow of the program by following code

```
var
  obj :TROOT;
begin
  if ((obj is TA) or (obj is TB) or (obj is TC) or (obj is TD)) then
  begin
    // some other codes here
  end
end;
```

this code works good but then I extend my code so more subclasses are derived from TROOT and that swtich appears at more than one place in the program. Is there any way I can put the class type into a set or array and have some psudeo code like following so I don't have to modify everywhere when the code is extended?

```
classarray = {TA, TB, TC, TD, TE, TF};
if (obj in classarray) then
begin
  // put my code here
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just test `if obj.InheritsFrom(TROOT)`.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for my case because not all class derived from TROOT are allowed.

Comment: Have you thought about using `interfaces` ?  If a thing supports an interface, do the code that uses that interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course put the classes in an array. Declare the types like this:

```
type
  TRootClass = class of TRoot;
  TRootClassArray = array of TRootClass;
```

Declare and populate the array:

```
var
  RootClasses: TRootClassArray;

SetLength(Classes, 4);
RootClasses[0] := TA;
RootClasses[1] := TB;
RootClasses[2] := TC;
RootClasses[3] := TD;
```

Then you can test the contents of the array:

```
var
  c: TRootClass;

for c in RootClasses do
  if obj is c then
    // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There are more and even better and OOP like ways to handle this.

- Class variables
- Custom Attributes
- [Visitor Pattern](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/17/the-visitor-pattern-part-4/)

or as a very simple approach (but also limited)

```
TROOT = class
...
end;

// just an dummy class to identify
TROOTALLOWED = class(TROOT)
end;

TA = class( TROOTALLOWED )
end;

TB = class( TROOT )
end;

TC = class( TROOTALLOWED )
end;
```

and in code

```
if obj is TROOTALLOWED then
```

Answer (score 1):

declare a abstract function on superclass and override the function on inherited classes.

```
TROOT = class
  function HasFeature1:Boolean;virtual;abstract;
end;


// just an dummy class to identify
TA= class(TROOT)
  function HasFeature1:Boolean;override;

end;

 if obj.HasFeature1 then // obj:TRoot
 begin
   // do something
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people are inviting "brand new bicycles" here, making ad hoc arrays and such. Looks like classic "NIH syndrome".

However one just could give a think how VCL was implemented and how its `RegisterClass` routine does its work. A little cat-like curiosity should be a professiona lrequirement for programmer ;-)

A little investigation into aforementioned routine would show you a very very typical thing for Delphi - ready-made TList container.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Contnrs.TClassList

So, that code

```
classarray = {TA, TB, TC, TD, TE, TF};
if (obj in classarray) then
begin
  // put my code here
end
```

translates into something like

```
var classarray : TClassList; ci: TClass;
...
classarray := TClassList.Create;
for ci in (TA, TB, TC, TD, TE, TF) do classarray.Add(ci);
....

if classarray.IndexOf(obj.Class) >= 0  then
begin
  // put my code here
end
....

classarray.Free;
```